# All values don't show up in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my Jsoup code

```
try {    
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200214036/women-watches.html?spm=2114.search0103.3.7.765d221bi3J3Io&site=glo&g=y").get();
        Elements titleElement = document.select("div.item > div.has-sku-image > a");
        Elements imageElement = document.select("div.item > div.img > div.pic > a.picRind > img");
        Elements priceElement = document.select("div.item > div.info > span.price");

        int i = 0;
        String imagesSource[] = new String[imageElement.size()];
        String titlesSource[] = new String[titleElement.size()];
        String pricesSource[] = new String[titleElement.size()];

        int j = imageElement.size();

        for(i=0; i <= j; i++){
            //check if src value is empty, which is true if the src attr does not exist
            if(!imageElement.get(i).attr("abs:src").isEmpty()){
                imagesSource[i] = imageElement.get(i).attr("abs:src");
                titlesSource[i] = titleElement.get(i).attr("title");
                pricesSource[i] = priceElement.get(i).text();
                System.out.println(imagesSource[i]);
                System.out.println(titlesSource[i]);
                System.out.println(pricesSource[i]);
            }
            else{
                imagesSource[i] = imageElement.get(i).attr("abs:image-src");
                titlesSource[i] = titleElement.get(i).attr("title");
                System.out.println(imagesSource[i]);
                System.out.println(titlesSource[i]);     
                System.out.println(pricesSource[i]);
            }                

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Crawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

All are okay bur prices don't show up for all. First 6 have prices but others have null in price value.

Why is this happening? All values have the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing

```
pricesSource[i] = priceElement.get(i).text();
```

at `else` part.